# 'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used' error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app and am now getting this error. I don't know why. I've tried looking at every other StackOverflow post about this error, and I tried all the suggestions, but nothing worked. Here is the code:

```
class ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
int counter = 0;
List scrambles = ["F R U R' U' F'", 'F U R B D', 'D B2 U2 S'];

void incrementCounter() {
setState(() {
  counter++;
  });
}

bool active = false;

void _handleTapboxChanged(bool newValue) {
setState(() {
  active = newValue;
    });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SizedBox(
  child: TapboxB(
    active: active,
    onChanged: _handleTapboxChanged,
    scrambles: scrambles,
    counter: counter,
    incrementCounter: incrementCounter(), **This is where the error occurs**
        ),
    );
  }
 }
```

And here you can see I made this 'incrementCounter' method required for TapBoxB. The reason why I made this 'incrementCounter' required was so that I could call the method inside the onPressed(){} of the TextButton(). Any help is appreciated.

```
class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
 final bool active;
 final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  final List scrambles; 
 final int counter; 
 final int incrementCounter;

 const TapboxB({
super.key,
this.active = false,
required this.incrementCounter,
required this.onChanged,
required this.scrambles, 
required this.counter, 
 });

 void _handleTap() {
onChanged(!active);
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GestureDetector(
  onTap: _handleTap,
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: null),
    child: Center(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          incrementCounter;
        },
        child: Text('${scrambles[counter % scrambles.length]}'),
      ),
      // child: Text('Ignore this)
      //     ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
    }
```

If anyone can provide an answer and explain how they fixed the error, that'd be great.

Comment: `incrementCounter: incrementCounter()` is calling the `incrementCounter` function and trying to supply its return value (which is nothing) as the argument to the `incrementCounter` named parameter.  What you intend is just `incrementCounter: incrementCounter` (which passes the `incrementCounter` function itself as the argument to the `incrementCounter` named parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is within your code:

```dart
SizedBox(
      child: TapboxB(
        active: active,
        onChanged: _handleTapboxChanged,
        scrambles: scrambles,
        counter: counter,
        incrementCounter: incrementCounter(), // This line is the problem since it's calling the function instead of passing the function
      ),
    );
```

You are calling the function using parenthesis `()`,instead you should just pass a reference to it.

```dart
TapboxB(
          active: active,
          onChanged: _handleTapboxChanged,
          scrambles: scrambles,
          counter: counter,
          incrementCounter: incrementCounter // without the () since it's just a reference
          )
```

Also, in your code, you are accepting it as an `int` but it should really be a `function`.

Instead of:

```dart
class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
  final int incrementCounter;
  final bool active;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
```

Use:

```dart
class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() incrementCounter;
  final bool active;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is just about getting tap event, I will suggest using `VoidCallback`.

```dart
class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback incrementCounter;

  const TapboxB({
    super.key,
    required this.incrementCounter,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: incrementCounter,
    );
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
TapboxB(
  incrementCounter: incrementCounter,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

method `incrementCounter()` doesn't return a value as evidenced by the keyword `void`:

```
void incrementCounter() {
setState(() {
  counter++;
  });
}
```

in the same time `TapboxB(...)` expect `incrementCounter` that is `int`.
that's why you got an error:
'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used'.

you should pas `int`:

```
Tabbox(
  incrementCounter: <--- here
)
```

or you should use `void Function()` or `VoidCallback` in the Tabbox:

```
class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onIncrementCounter;

  const TapboxB({
    super.key,
    required this.onIncrementCounter,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: onIncrementCounter,
    );
  }
}
```